How to apply css inside li tag using outside element?
I'm trying to apply css inside list element
<ol>
<li>abcd</li>
<li>defg</li>
</ol>
<p>list color change</p>

Styles:
ol>li:has(+p){color:red;}

but it's not working can anyone suggest me the exact style using has property.

You're applying the :has selector to any li, none of which have a sibling of type p.
You need to apply it to the ol
ol:has(+p)>li{color:red;}

